# Can not delete file from windows application which is under iis application

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have windows service application whose relevant lines:

```
try {
  if (File.Exists(outputPath)) {
    File.Delete(outputPath);
  }

  File.Copy(archivePath, outputPath);
  return true;
} catch (Exception ex) {
  //Exception: UnauthorizedAccessException
}
```

at `File.Delete(...)` line for the file

```
c:\inetpub\myapp\somefile.rar
```

I got

```
UnauthorizedAccessException
```

At this moment when I tried to open rar it gives:

```
Cannot open c:\inetpub\myapp\somefile.rar
```

and `http://myhost/myapp/somefile.rar`

give Http Error 401.3 Unauthorized error

until I recycle application pool, I can not be deleted from windows explorer neither

When I recycle pool, it got deleted file

What could be issue, and settings that I can delete file from win service application?

Note: similar configuration runs on another customer location

**Edit**: while running process monitor, error does not occur

Comment: Are you sure the user has rights to delete the file? it could just be read + execute

Comment: @BugFinder File can be deleted when application pool recycled

Comment: The file is being used by iis process that's why you can't delete it. App pool recycle releases the lock on the file that's why you can delete it.